# Uso de diversas imagens de boa qualidade no sqlite

Tags: android, imagem, sqlite

Preciso sanar uma duvida de como utilizar da melhor forma gravação de diversas imagens de boa resolução no banco de dados. Melhor definição seria efetuar toda e qualquer operação do sqlite em diversas imagens de diversas resoluções de boa qualidade. Vi alguma coisa sobre usar blob e gravar em array de bytes e queria ver se é o melhor caminho. O aplicativo é um cardápio que atualizará as imagens do banco de tempos em tempos e usará muito pesquisa para popular imageviews entre outros componentes.

Comment: Podes guardar as imagens no cartão SD, e depois quando as precisares de carregar ficarem em cache. Fiz exatamente a mesma app que tu e foi assim que fiz.

Comment: @JorgeB. o que quer dizer com ficar em cache? Como disse que já fez exatamente isso poderia responder a pergunta.

Comment: @Math A pergunta é "como utilizar da melhor forma gravação de diversas imagens?". A ideia é guardar o caminho (*path*) para a imagem na Base de Dados(numa string). Depois, através dessa *path*, carregar a imagem previamente guardada no cartão SD. Pode e deve utilizar as API's de [MemoryCache](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) para não ter que estar sempre a carregar a imagem do cartão SD, para que a aplicação se mantenha mais estável.

Comment: @JorgeB, obrigado pelo comentário.  No caso seria utilizado esta app em tablets que não tem SD. Caso seja gravado as imagens em memória interna, teria como eu ler, alterar e apaga las.  Porque a idéia seria de tempos em tempos verificar no servidor se existe uma atualização de algum dado e atualizar esta informação. A chave da minha pergunta é consumo mínimo de bateria e bom desempenho.

Comment: Encontrei [isto](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20280440/1817673), acho que é a melhor forma de fazer tendo em conta as tuas premissas de consumo e de desempenho. De qualquer forma eu utilizaria na mesma as API's de MemoryCache que eu falei anteriormente.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Desculpem a demora... Havia testado, porém o consumo de bateria acima do normal existe nestes casos e, não sei se eu estou desenvolvendo algo errado, o desempenho esta abaixo do esperado com alguns delays.

Comment: @VictorCS achou alguma solução?

Comment: Wellington Avelino não encontrei solução que consuma pouca bateria e que seja de boa utilização.

Comment: @VictorCS, esse app vai rodar em tablets(mesa de restaurante) ? precisa mesmo ser em alta qualidade?

Comment: Sim... querem dar foco aos pratos (imagem).

Comment: @VictorCS, não é viavel salvar na memória interna? qual o tamanho de cada imagem?